# I am using ESBuild to compile JS in the browser. When I attempt to import CSS, I get [ERROR] Unexpected "." How can i go about fixing this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, esbuild

I am building a JS notebook that runs in the browser. I am using ESBuild to do the compiling. I am trying to get it to handle a CSS import such as <import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'>. No matter what, I get the following error:

✘ [ERROR] Unexpected "."

```
a:https://unpkg.com/bulma/css/bulma.css:3:0:
  3 │ .button, .input, .textarea, .select select, .file-cta,
    ╵ ^
```

I have written the plugin for handling onLoad() to deal with CSS, but it seems my program is not even making it that far before it errors.

Here is the plugin:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild-wasm';
import localforage from 'localforage';

const fileCache = localforage.createInstance({
  name: 'fileCache',
});

export const outputCodeFetcher = (inputCode: string) => {
  return {
    name: 'output-code-fetch',
    setup(build: esbuild.PluginBuild) {
      build.onLoad({ filter: /.*/ }, async (args: esbuild.OnLoadArgs) => {
        if (args.path === 'index.js') {
          return {
            loader: 'jsx',
            contents: inputCode,
          };
        }

        const cachedResult = await fileCache.getItem(args.path);

        if (cachedResult) {
          return cachedResult;
        }

        const { data, request } = await axios.get(args.path);

        console.log(request);

        const fileType = args.path.match(/.css$/) ? 'css' : 'jsx';

        const escapedData = (data: string) => {
          return data
            .replace(/\n/g, '')
            .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
            .replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        };

        const contents =
          fileType === 'css'
            ? `
          const style = document.createElement('style');
          style.innerText = '${escapedData(data)}';
          document.head.appendChild(style);
        `
            : data;
        const axiosResult = {
          loader: 'jsx',
          contents: contents,
          resolveDir: new URL('./', request.responseURL).pathname,
        };

        await fileCache.setItem(args.path, axiosResult);
        return axiosResult;
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Here is the app that runs the ESBuild instance:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  inputCodePathResolver,
  outputCodeFetcher,
  startEsbuildService,
} from './plugins';

const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  const onClick = async () => {
    const esBuildRef = await startEsbuildService();
    // const result = await esBuildRef.transform(input, {
    //   loader: 'jsx',
    //   target: 'es2015',
    // });
    const result = await esBuildRef.build({
      entryPoints: ['index.js'],
      sourcemap: 'external',
      bundle: true,
      write: false,
      plugins: [inputCodePathResolver(), outputCodeFetcher(input)],
      define: {
        // 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
        global: 'window',
      },
      outdir: 'out',
    });
    console.log(result);

    setCode(result.outputFiles[1].text);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <textarea
          value={input}
          onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <div>
          <button onClick={onClick}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <pre>{code}</pre>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you for any insight.

I have tried to format the CSS file to handle the CSS in a JS snippet, but I don't believe the program is making it that far. I have tried reformatting the instance of ESBuild in the app, but I have gotten no results from that either. I also tried to get esbuild-sass-plugin to work with esbuild-wasm, but no luck there either. I have scoured all related questions on SO and cannot find a case of this specific problem with a viable solution.

Comment: esbuild comes with inbuilt support for `css`. So why are you trying to make a plugin?

Comment: The plugin is not specifically for handling CSS. ESBuild natively works with a file system. I'm having it handle code written in a form by a user in the browser. ESBuild has to find any imported modules online instead of in a file system. And its default behavior is to write any CSS into a file as well. But we're running in a browser and so have no file system. Thus the plugin.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you have a public repo I can take a look at?

Comment: Of course. https://github.com/NMurdaugh/js-browser-notebook

Comment: Are your changes in `main` branch? Because my `npm run build` works fine.

Comment: Yes. Type the following in the input in the browser, and you'll see the error I'm talking about in the console.      import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'

Comment: Vs if you were to import react from 'react', it would present you the fetched and compiled code just fine.

Comment: Doesn't look like I'm getting any error: https://i.imgur.com/HmFDXUQ.png (only error in my console is 404 from favicon not found). Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Now THAT is interesting.

Comment: So it works. Just not on my machine. That's a new one.

Comment: Could be a cache issue. Delete your `node_modules`. Then do a fresh install with `npm ci`. Then delete all your cache build directories: `dist`, `.vite` and then run `npm run dev` and check if issue persists.

Comment: I just set up a Codespace for it, and it works fine there. But if I run it from my actual machine, I get [https://imgur.com/a/CkLgcuW](https://imgur.com/a/CkLgcuW)

Comment: I'll do that now, thanks!

Comment: Looks like it was a caching issue specifically with Opera on the particular port I've been running the server on since the start. Thank you so much. It's such a silly problem that I never would have found without your help, and it's been bothering me for a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

I have cloned your repo, and then started dev server: `npm run dev`.

[image]

As you can see, I have no errors. In this case, I suspect that its some caching issue on your end.

1. Delete your `node_modules`, and then reinstall dependencies using `npm ci`.
2. Delete your build directory: `dist`, `.vite`. Restart server using `npm run dev`.
3. Take a look and see where else it can cached